# Solving Initial Value Problem based on Advection Equation

Tags: integration

Having some trouble with an Initial value problem based on the advection equation:

$$ u_t + cu_x = 0,    t > 0 $$

The problem itself is:

$$ u_t - x^2tu_x = 0, u(x,0) = x + 1 $$

Using the same method as I have other problems of this nature, I end up with a solution that doesn't fit the initial conditions, so perhaps someone can point out where I have gone wrong? Following the example of other problems of this format:

Slope of characteristic curves is $$ dx/dt = c(x,t) = -x^2t $$

Solving this for the characteristic curve equation I obtain:

$$-\int_{} 1/x^2 dx = \int_{}t dt$$

$$ x = 2/t^2 + K $$    (where K is a constant).

Letting (x,t) be an arbitrary point where we want to obtain a solution, it can be said the characteristic curve passing through (x,t) will pass through the x axis at (E,0) where the equation is:

$$x = 2/t^2 + E $$

Since u is constant along this curve:

$$ u(x,t) = u(E,0) = E + 1 = x - 2/t^2 + 1$$

However this fails the initial conditions. I can't see where I've gone wrong though, having followed a method that worked for a simpler c(x,t).Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, I think you just did your algebra wrong.

After integrating separately 'x' and 't' and then solving for 'x', I believe you made an error.

The integrals give:

$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{t^{2}}{2} + K$$

Simplifying

$$x = \frac{1}{(\frac{t^{2}}{2}+K)}$$

You could (if you wanted) pull out a factor of 1/2 in the denominator to get:

$$x = \frac{2}{t^{2}+2K}$$

But generally speaking, you cannot just invert the t^2/2 term like you have or divide the numerator by each term in the denominator. That algebra is incorrect.

Comment: woops... made the fix and was able to solve the problem. cheers